# php backslash find and replace

Tags: php, replace

I am trying to do a simple find and replace within a string with:

```
$share_name = str_replace(" ", "\ ", $share_name );
```

Unfortunately for some reason it replaces all the spaces with "\\ " instead of "\ ". Does anybody know whats going on and how to solve this problem?

Comment: The 3 `"\ "` seem identical with quote, backslash, space, quote. No?

Comment: What exactly do you want to replace with which?

Comment: Replaces all the spaces with "\ " instead of "\ ".  I can't actually see any difference between "\ " and "\ ".

Comment: I've edited the question to make the backslash-backslash different than the single backslash. Apparently stackoverflow escapes slashes or something.

Comment: Actually your code works for me ;)

Comment: It works for me too. I think the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
$share_name = str_replace(" ", "\\ ", $share_name );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the `\` character.

```
$share_name = str_replace(" ", "\\ ", $share_name );
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you call it twice? Are you adding slashes before you echo it out or write it to the DB? Is magic_quotes on?

Your code is fine and should work. The problem is elsewhere.